# Proper HIPAA security

Tags: web-application, email, hipaa

I am a sysadmin, though not security-specific.  I was recently stunned to receive an automated email from my physician's office (in USA) containing an HTTP link to their website for the completion of preregistration forms.

Starting on a clean browser and a different computer, I followed the link to their website forms, which required only my last name and birth date to have access to my entire health history, insurance payment plan, Social Security number, etc.  To be sure, I obtained my own birthdate from a web search (mylife.com, actually was the first hit) in 2 seconds.

Since email is in no way a secure transmission, can this possibly be HIPAA compliant?

Comment: this is pretty easy to look up. I used "hipaa compliance tls" and got a bunch of hits: https://luxsci.com/blog/level-ssl-tls-required-hipaa.html

Comment: You seem to be (rightfully) concerned that someone who was in a position to intercept the email that your received from your heakthcare provider could have easily accessed your protected health information (PHI) using the link in the email, and a few other pieces of easy to find information (i.e. your name and your date of birth).  In this case, the barrier to accessing your PHI is only marginally (at best) higher than if the PHI had been sent in the email itself.

Comment: So, the question comes down to whether or not it is acceptable to send PHI by email.  It turns out that in some cases, this is allowed.  See https://www.securitymetrics.com/static/resources/orange/HIPAA_Compliant_Emails_White_Paper.pdf for some interesting reading on this subject.

Comment: @mti2935 email is not the important factor here. The email contained a link. If the link was generic, then the system to consider is the website. If the link was specific to the user, then we're still not talking about PHI over email.

Comment: @schroeder WRT '...then we're still not talking about PHI over email'.  True, the PHI is not sent through email - but instead, a link to the PHI is sent.  An attacker that is in a position to intercept the email (perhaps at one of the MTA's that the email passes through) can easily access the PHI using the link in the intercepted email.  So, it would seem that the same restrictions pertaining to sending PHI through email should apply - regardless of whether the PHI itself is sent, or a link the PHI is sent.  If not, then this is a loophole that should be closed.

Comment: @mti2935, yes, that is my precise concern.  The email was _not_ sent in any secure, encrypted, or verified manner--just a regular plain text email, containing a link that trivially allowed access to PHI.  The only "work" an attacker need do is find my last name and DOB given my email and first name (both in the email).  I did it in seconds.

Comment: @cchroeder, thank you for the link and your analysis.  I had the same thought, but was half-convinced I had missed something.  The practice has literally hundreds of doctors, and significant protection over the paper forms.  To have implemented this way seemed like I was missing something--and I didn't want to confront without a second opinion.  Apparently, I didn't miss anything, and they are simply careless or incompetent.  FWIW, the regular login to their patient portal, which truly had my entire medical record requires only a username (email address) and any type of password.